# finally and rethowing of exception in except, raise in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

```
try:
   #error code
except Exception as e:
   print 'error',e
   raise miexp("malicious error")  
   #userdefined exception, miexp
finally:
   print 'finally'
```

Why the output is in the following formats?

Output:

```
error
finally
malicious error
```

Actually I expected as:

```
error
malicious error
finally
```

Why so?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`miexp("malicious error")` isn't handled, therefore it will end the execution of the program. On the other hand, the `finally` block is *guaranteed* to be executed.

To ensure this Python executes the `finally` block *before* actually raising the exception. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally):

> If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The finally clause is executed. If there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the finally clause.