# Understanding Control flow in Exception Handling in Python

Tags: python, exception, control-flow, flowchart

```
a=0
try:
    print("In Try Block !")
    a = 10/0
except Exception as e:
    print("In Exception Block !")
    raise e
finally:
    print("In Finally Block !")
    print(a)
    pass
```

When I run the above code I get output as below. I don't get the flow of this script.

```
In Try Block !
Traceback (most recent call last):
In Exception Block !
In Finally Block !
0
  File "C:\Users\reccer\Documents\Practicals\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\reccer\Documents\Practicals\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = 10/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

1. Enters try block.
2. founds error
3. Enters except block.
4. prints *"In Exception Block !"*
5. Enters finally block.
6. prints *"In Finally Block !"* & prints *a*.
7. then performs formalities of *raise e* from except block.

I can't get any concrete reference for flow of control.

Comment: A number can't be divided by zero

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand here?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was expecting that `except` block will execute once at all, then it will go in `finally` block. But as we can see it executes `print` statement and then goes to `final` block, then comes back to `except` block and `raise e` is executed.

Comment: @jarmod flow of excecution of the above script.

Comment: It's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249269/finally-and-rethowing-of-exception-in-except-raise-in-python

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 I understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is correct. The finally block is executed before leaving the try\except\finally structure. Since you re-raised the exception, the exception is being passed out of the structure, so finally must run first.

```
a=0
try:
    print("In Try Block !")
    a = 10/0
except Exception as e:
    print("In Exception Block !")
    raise e   # send exception up the call stack, but must run finally first 
finally:
    print("In Finally Block !")
    print(a)
    pass   # not needed
```

The error trace you see is generated by the code that called your code - probably the core python engine.